# My neighbour is rich. I want in on that

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I noticed that my dear neighbourino has a considerable amount of cash just laying around.

**Is there any way I can relieve him of it?** Or is that money frozen in his Swiss bank account, for his heir to inherit? What if his heir is unlanded?

He is an Emir, under a Sultan liege, and only has one holding left.

I, as a Catholic King, have a holy war casus belli on him. I can also straight up usurp his Emirate, as I own 100% of the de jure territory – this will give me a de jure claim CB.

I also own 95% of the de jure territory in the Sultanate, so I can also usurp that title, thus making the good Emir independent. Not sure if it is useful, other than voiding the truce I have with the Sultan.

Comment: I didn't understand half the vocabulary used but I still loved the question :D

Comment: I saw this question in the Hot Network Questions column on another site, completely out of context. It wasn't until after reading the answer that I realized it was about a game.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First, usurp his liege's title. This will cause him to become independent and, more importantly, gives you a de jure claim on his county.

Press the de jure claim. You need to do this instead of holy warring because holy war will only take his title (and he'll move to another court).

When you win, you'll vassalise him. Revoke his title. Hopefully, since he hates you, he'll refuse. This will allow you to imprison him without tyranny.

Once he's imprisoned and his title has been revoked, banish him. You'll get all his money.

Comment: Oh, that is devious – and it does make sense. I may upset a lot of people in the process, though (due to the extra kingdom and possible tyranny points). I will probably be really unpopular – but I'll also be stinking rich, which is a comfort.

Comment: With at least Medium Crown Authority the attempt to revoke his title won't even anger your own vassals. Medium Crown Authority makes Revoking Infidel titles free.

You say you own 95% of the Sultanate. Does the current Sultan own any of the remaining 5%? I know from hard experience that you cannot revoke the top-tier title off of a character of a different religion if he owns territory within the title's de jure area. Unless he owns more than one of his top-tier title.

Comment: @CrusaderJ The Emir owns the last holding in the de jure Sultanate. I can usurp the Sultanate, but it will actually get me negative opinion from my current vassals (who now desires the new Kingdom). It will also likely reset the de jure drift into my primary Kingdom.

Comment: @Studoku Is there a way to vassalize the Emir without usurping titles? I can get a de jure claim by creating the duchy his last and only holding belongs to.

Comment: @Nix If the Emir has no vassals outside of his only remaining County, a de jure ducal claim on his only County will vassalize him to you. If he has any vassals outside of his one held County he will take one of their titles and remain the vassal of the sultan while you take the county title from him.

Comment: That's nicer than King Phillip was to the Templars.

Comment: Banishing the Templars and taking their stuff is also in this game.

Comment: @Studoku I created the duchy, and declared war on the liege for my de jure territory. However, the duke did not become my count-vassal – now he is simply unlanded. Should I have usurped his other duchy first? Or did he have to be independent?

Comment: @Nix He needed to be a count with a single county level title.

Comment: That's annoying. I figured it would work, since he only held a single county. I went back to an earlier save, usurped his title, and now he becomes a vassal as you say, even if I don't understand why. Unfortunatelly, he is cool with me revoking the county – so I need to find another way to lock him up. :)

Comment: @Nix You'll just have to eat the tyranny and directly imprison I suppose?

Comment: @Affine I'm actually contemplating giving him his duchy back, then revoke that one year later (minimum time needed to revoke a granted title). Maybe he will be less willing to let me revoke a duchy than a county.